# Достать все тексты кнопок

Tags: python, telebot

Есть такой вот вывод:

> ReplyInlineMarkup(rows=[KeyboardButtonRow(buttons=[KeyboardButtonCallback(text='1BUTTON', data=b'choose-method-tinkoff', requires_password=False)]), KeyboardButtonRow(buttons=[KeyboardButtonCallback(text='2BUTTON', data=b'choose-method-sberbank', requires_password=False)]), KeyboardButtonRow(buttons=[KeyboardButtonCallback(text='3BUTTON', data=b'choose-method-alfabank', requires_password=False)]), KeyboardButtonRow(buttons=[KeyboardButtonCallback(text='4BUTTON', data=b'choose-method-vtb', requires_password=False)]), KeyboardButtonRow(buttons=[KeyboardButtonCallback(text='5BUTTON', data=b'choose-method-SystemFastPayments', requires_password=False)]), KeyboardButtonRow(buttons=[KeyboardButtonCallback(text='6BUTTON', data=b'choose-method-yoomoney', requires_password=False)]), KeyboardButtonRow(buttons=[KeyboardButtonCallback(text='7BUTTON', data=b'choose-method-payeer', requires_password=False)]), KeyboardButtonRow(buttons=[KeyboardButtonCallback(text='· 1 ·', data=b'payment-methods-page-0', requires_password=False), KeyboardButtonCallback(text='2', data=b'payment-methods-page-1', requires_password=False)]), KeyboardButtonRow(buttons=[KeyboardButtonCallback(text='‹ Назад', data=b'back', requires_password=False)])])

Вывод должен быть

```
x = {"1BUTTON","2BUTTON","3BUTTON","4BUTTON","5BUTTON","6BUTTON","7BUTTON","Назад"}
```

Как вывести все тексты кнопок в один словарь?
Заранее огромное спасибо!

Comment: судя по всему, в русском языке вы тоже недавно...

Comment: `x = { btn.text for row in input.rows for btn in row.buttons }`  Или проблема в чем-то другом?